# skin as a countable noun example

Tags: grammar, countable-nouns

‎Could you please write an example where skin would be used as a countable noun?

I have just learned that it can be used both as a countable and an uncountable noun.

Thank you.

Comment: [Google Books_ United States Customs Court Reports: Cases Adjudged in the United ..., Vol 18](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zJTPAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22seven+skins%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=cbJIWLpSJZ&sig=ACfU3U3fxjNKOY2B2I35ojQn_eoYmu1t-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH79e35IvpAhWlQkEAHQF_C1cQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22seven%20skins%22%20meaning&f=false) (p 39; bottom of page)

Comment: One skin from a bear and two untanned skins from Lynx.

Answer (score 3):

The form "skins" is often used to refer to pelts of animals in the context of hunting.

There are quite a number of other cases as well when this form is appropriate. For example, the term is used to describe thin strips taken from the outside layer of something, like a vegetable, as in "onion skins". Stuffed "baked potato skins" are a popular snack or meal in North America.

For many other examples, see https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/skins.html.

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> At some time about 1500 B.C. the Aryan-speaking people poured into India. They had fair skins and probably came from western Asia, and were akin to the ancient Iranians.

“Medical Advance, Public Health and Social Evolution:...” By Charles Wilcocks

> She held Dolora by the arms and shoulders until she surrendered to her embrace. Nana could feel the child who would one day name herself moving against their two skins

"Water Marked: A Novel" by Helen Elaine Lee

Comment: Neither of those sound natural to me. (for two different reasons).

Comment: Nevertheless, they are correct and not uncommon constructions. :)